# Error while trying to invoke Golang trace

Tags: go, trace

The following command works fine serving up a web page with a profile and I am able to analyse it, very good.

```
go tool pprof -http=:8082 https://mytestserver.net:443/debug/pprof/profile?seconds=3
```

However if I try a trace, this happens

```
$ go tool pprof -http=:8082 https://mytestserver.net:443/debug/pprof/trace?seconds=3
Fetching profile over HTTP from https://mytestserver.net:443/debug/pprof/trace?seconds=3
https://mytestserver.net:443/debug/pprof/trace?seconds=3: server response: 404 Not Found - Unknown profile
failed to fetch any source profiles
```

This doesn't work either

```
$ go tool trace -http=:8082 https://mytestserver.net:443/debug/pprof/trace?seconds=3
2020/09/29 22:34:49 Parsing trace...
failed to open trace file: open https://mytestserver.net:443/debug/pprof/trace?seconds=3: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Was following some examples from
https://jvns.ca/blog/2017/09/24/profiling-go-with-pprof/

Trace could be useful to visualize GC behaviour as well as Goroutine/Threads etc.

Is there another way to generate trace?

I run trace from a Windows machine and the following is the versioning info

```
$ go version
go version go1.15.2 windows/amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using http instead of secure connection?
It seems it only works for http connections FYR.. https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit older, but at least with Go 1.20 I have the same problem, because `go tool trace` ONLY accepts files.

The https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/pprof docs also "hint" at this by first downloading the trace with `curl`, then opening it with `go tool trace`

```
curl -o trace.out http://localhost:6060/debug/pprof/trace?seconds=5
go tool trace trace.out
```